# Creating a multiSelection Function having trouble getting all values

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, built-in

Ok so this question is asking me to create a function based on the mouse coordinates and the dimensions of each text box but i cant figure out how to include every instance where at least one point is touching the line of mouse start and end.

```js
function multiSelection(dimensions, tasks, mouseCoordinates) {
  var inDrag = [];
  var width = dimensions[0];
  var height = dimensions[1];
  var spaceHeight = dimensions[2];

  if (mouseCoordinates[0][1] > mouseCoordinates[1][1]) {
    var LineStart = mouseCoordinates[1][1];
    var LineEnd = mouseCoordinates[0][1];
  } else {
    var LineStart = mouseCoordinates[0][1];
    var LineEnd = mouseCoordinates[1][1];
  }

  var pos = 0
  for (var i = 0; i <= tasks.length; i++) {
    pos = pos + height + spaceHeight
    if (LineStart < pos && pos < LineEnd) {
      inDrag.push(tasks[i]);
    }
  }
  return inDrag;
}

console.log(
  multiSelection(
    [135, 9, 1],
    ["Task 1", "Task 2", "Task 3", "Very Important Task", "Not So Important Task", "Yet Another Task", "The last task"],
    [ [132, 42], [35, 13] ]
  )
);
```

Comment: So whats the problem?

Comment: when i run the code it should return Task 2", "Task 3", "Very Important Task","Not So Important Task" but it only returns Task 2", "Task 3", "Very Important Task"

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: im not sure what that is lol

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code for possible scenarios and commented it; take a look.
I'm not sure your are asking an actual question which worth staying on StackOverflow, but anyway, you have problem with your inputs.

```
function multiSelection(dimensions, tasks, mouseCoordinates) {
  var inDrag = [];
  var width = dimensions[0]; // 135
  var height = dimensions[1]; // 9
  var spaceHeight = dimensions[2]; // 1

  if (mouseCoordinates[0][1] > mouseCoordinates[1][1]) { // 42 > 13 = true
    var LineStart = mouseCoordinates[1][1]; // 13
    var LineEnd = mouseCoordinates[0][1]; // 42
  } else {
    var LineStart = mouseCoordinates[0][1]; // 42
    var LineEnd = mouseCoordinates[1][1]; // 13
  }

  var pos = 0
  for (var i = 0; i <= tasks.length; i++) { // 7 times
    pos = pos + height + spaceHeight // pos + 9 + 1
    if (LineStart < pos && pos < LineEnd) { 
        // 1st time: 13 < 10 && 10 < 42
        // 2nd time: 13 < 11 && 11 < 42
        // 3rd time: 13 < 12 && 12 < 42
        // 4th time: 13 < 13 is false, end of possibilities!
      inDrag.push(tasks[i]);
    }
  }
  return inDrag;
}

console.log(
  multiSelection(
    [135, 9, 1],
    ["Task 1", "Task 2", "Task 3", "Very Important Task", "Not So Important Task", "Yet Another Task", "The last task"],
    [ [132, 42], [35, 13] ]
  )
);
```